# how can i make edge wear and cavity masks on low poly mesh?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, shaders

I have really low poly models that i want to add wear on edges and dirt in crevices to. The geometry pointiness node works only with high poly, the ambient occlusion node gives me bad results and the bevel node uses both the edges and crevices at once which i don't want, and vertex painting gives me bad results as well. i want to be able to use the two masks separately to have a darker color in the crevices and a lighter color on the worn edges for example. Is there a way to do that in cycles with nodes on a low poly mesh? Or is manual texture painting the only way?